# How to use model int array variable in javascript MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

**Model**

```
public int[] mobileid{get;set;}
```

**Script**

```
var k;
for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
{
  k=@model.mobileid[i];
  alert(k);
}
```

This method not working,How to assign `int` array variable to Javascript `var`. I already use below method:

```
var k=[];
k=@html.Raw(json.Encode(model.mobileid));//not work
```

Comment: `var k = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.year))` will work fine (I assume you just have some typos (capital H, J and M)

Comment: var k = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.year)); End of semicolon (;) showing syntax error

Comment: Remove the semicolon (see my comment)

Comment: When remove semicolon ,error showing next line

Comment: I don't kow what your next line is :) But if you want to use the semicolon you can use `var k= JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.mobileid))');`

Comment: Can't see any reason why you would not getting it. Are you saying that you do get the other positions? Try `$.each(k, function(index, item) { console.log('index: ' + item); });` and check the output.

Comment: I now see from your acceptance of the answer (an awful way to solve your problem) that the model was null. You just need to check for `null` first - `if (k) { for(var i=0;i<3;i++) { var x = k[i]; } }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke First my problem is how to get model element in script side,Then new problems came for null reference exception,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your `Model.mobileid` to a string with a separator of your choice and convert it to a javascript array:

```
<script>
    var k = "@(Model.mobileid == null ? string.Empty : string.Join(",", Model.mobileid))";
    alert(k);
    k = k.split(",");
    k // k is an array at this point
</script>
```

Comment: Its work good,But one issue,`if(a==b) { var k = "@(string.Join(",", Model.mobileid))";//Now my mobileid is null, 
    alert(k);} `     if condition is false,but it goes to if block,then show the null reference exception error.

Comment: updated my code. You can as well check the value of `k` after the first line before further operations.

Comment: Yep,My model.mobileid is null

Comment: `model` not `model.mobileid`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87889/discussion-between-oluwafemi-and-mano-johnbritto).

Comment: I can't understand ,Which model?

Comment: click on continue this discussion in chat so we can resolve this much faster